# Why do I have by default a prefilled name in my dropdown whereas I want to display 'Select' by default using react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

can someone see why in my `Dropdown` menu, I have by default a name filled, whereas I'd like to have by default `Select`. What is wrong please ?

```
export default function Overview() {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState()
    const [questionDrop, setQuestionDrop] = useState()
    const [overview, setOverview] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        ClearApi.listQuestions()
            .then(res => {
                const i = res.data.questions
                console.log('Questions: ', i)
                setQuestions(i.map(i => ({ ...i, value: i._id, name: i.title })))
                if (i.length > 0) setQuestionDrop(i[0])
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (questionDrop !== undefined)
            myfunctionAPI.displayOverview(questionDrop._id)
                .then(res => {
                    const d = res.data.overviews
                    console.log('Overview: ', d)
                    setOverview(d)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
    }, [questionDrop]);

    return (
        <div >
            <Dropdown
                label={questionDrop?.title ?? 'Select'}
                items={questions}
                onSelect={({ value }) => setQuestionDrop(questions.find(i => i._id === value))}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `if (i.length > 0) setQuestionDrop(i[0])`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski where do I have to put `if (i.length > 0) setQuestionDrop(i[0])` ?

Comment: You already have this, remove it.